# neato node running under groovy

Tags: ros, neato, ros-groovy, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone got the ROS Neato node working in Groovy?

I have it working in feurte OK.  But in groovy it is giving me a missing driver declaration.  I've traced it to the

neato_node/node/neato.py  file -  here line 44 says   neato_driver.neato_driver.  And ROS tells me this file cannot be found.

In fuerte the same file, same line asks for just neato_driver   (no .neato_driver)   I tried changer the .py file to look like the fuerte driver with no success.  (The neato.py file has to be edited sometimes to change the USB port name to the correct driver in linux.   It defaults to ACM0,  but my port is USB0.

I got it via git -  set it into a workspace, did the init, rosdep update, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57634/neato-node-running-under-groovy/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the neato_node running on Unbuntu 11.10 and Groovy using http://ros.org/wiki/neato_node instructions with the added modification of changing USB0 to ACM0 on my laptop.

Unfortunately the same trick does not work using Raspberry Pi and Raspi. Both roslaunch and rosrun die at the same place - line 44 in the neato.py program. I believe that is where the USB port is specified.

rosrun neato_node neato.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0  doesn't seem to work for either platform for me.

One more clue - a ros_workspace package does work well on either platform.

---

Originally posted by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) with karma: 147 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0